# AWS Lambda(Java) debugging is not working in AWS Cloud9 IDE

Tags: aws-cloud9

AWS Lambda(Java) debugging is not working in  AWS Cloud9 IDE, but I can debug a java program. Does this tool support java based lambda debugging?